# Increase connSupervisionTimeout

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a question about connSupervisionTimeout.

I'm writing app with CoreBluetooth. I checked connection parameters and connSupervisionTimeout = 720ms. On the apple website I found that this parameter should be in the range: **2 seconds ≤ connSupervisionTimeout ≤ 6 seconds**. Is it possible to increase this using CoreBluetooth? If not how to do this?

Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control this as an iOS third party application ... only the connected accessory can initiate a connection parameter request change

Section 10.6 of the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf) I think you are reading alludes to this when it says:

> The accessory is responsible for the connection parameters used for the Low Energy connection. The accessory should request connection parameters appropriate for its use case by sending an L2CAP Connection Parameter

Do note, when a connection is initially established, the master of the connection dictates the starting parameter set used.

When the iOS kernel initiates a connection, I usually see it use a set with a 30 ms connection interval, 0 slave latency, and 720ms supervision timeout. I believe the documentation really only applies to future connection parameter change requests initiated by the accessory verse the initial set chosen by iOS